# I've always trusted Peter before or until now

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Which sentence is better?

> I've always trusted Peter before.

> I've always trusted Peter until now.

Now I don't trust him; I've just found he cheated on me.

I think "before"  is more natural than "until now", because I often see this usage. I've almost never seen the usage of "until now".

Comment: Perhaps "I _had_ always trusted Peter before/until now" is also worth considering.

Comment: [find out is the idiom]

Comment: It's surprising that you haven't seen "until now" often, since both "[have not ✻ before](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have+not+*+before%22)" and [have not ✻ until now](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have+not+*+until+now%22) are almost equally common in Google results.

Answer (score 9):

There are subtle differences between the two and their meanings change depending on their **primary** and *secondary* emphasis.

"I've **always** trusted Peter *before*" means you would consider trusting him again.

"I've always **trusted** Peter *before*" means you are now doubting his trustworthiness.

"I've always **trusted** Peter until *now*" means you no longer trust him.

Another possibility would be:

"I've always trusted **Peter** before (or until now)." This means you have some misgivings about trusting someone else.

Comment: An additional subtlety is that "I've always trusted Peter before" suggests a discrete series of events in which you trusted Peter and you are now looking at trusting him for another event (and as you say the emphasis matters).  "I've always trusted Peter until now" suggests that the trusting was something always there and that an event has just happened that has removed that trust.

Comment: Since 'before' points to an event in the past, I'd probably say either 'I had always trusted Peter before [he was arrested for fraud]' or 'I have always trusted Peter until now [that he has been arrested for fraud, or now that you have asked me]'.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian: Thank you very much, though they're really hard for me to digest.  "'I've *always* trusted Peter before' means you would consider trusting him again". Why this interpretation? Here is my guess: I'm now thinking of whether to trust Peter again. I used to *always* trust him and *always* got good results, so I'll trust him again. In the sentence, "before" implies "before this instance of considering whether to trust him or not". But, why can't "before" imply "before having just found he had cheated on me", why can't the sentence mean I used to always trust him, but now I don't?

Comment: @Stephen: Your guess is perfect! So... "why can't _before_ imply 'before having just found out he had cheated on me'"? Context! The word "before" might refer to **anything** that's just happened. Perhaps a mutual friend has just asked if you trust Peter to look after your flat while you're away. You say, "I've always trusted Peter before." meaning he has sometimes looked after your flat before. BUT if the friend has just told you Peter was once accused of arson, you might say the same words in horror! Suddenly you don't trust him! Btw, Note the words _consider_ and _doubting_ in my answer.

Comment: @Stephen: Do read all the comments. They're are all useful!

Answer (score 4):

This is the primary purpose of the past perfect tense: to describe an event that had occurred, that is to say it happened in the past tense and stopped happening in the past tense (i.e. no longer occurs in the present tense).

For example,

> I had always trusted Peter.

Or, using the contraction form in the OP

> I'd always trusted Peter.

Always seems redundant (likely used for empasis) so can be omitted

> I had trusted Peter.

Or contraction form

> I'd trusted Peter.

With the exception of irregular forms, past perfect tense uses 'had' with the past tense of the verb (e.g. 'had trusted'). Slight modofication from the 'have' you have in the OP which interprets the sentence in present perfect tense.

You can also omit the 'had' and use a temporal modifier such as 'before', which is also past perfect tense:

> I trusted Peter before.

Note the absence of 'had' or 'have'.

You can use a more specific temporal modifier as well

> I trusted Peter yesterday.

But do not combine the temporal modifier with 'had'.

Comment: What is wrong with using a temporal modifier with 'had'? "I trusted Peter yesterday" doesn't imply anything about today. "I had trusted Peter yesterday" seems to imply the trust no longer exists.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Brandon It is redundant. Additionally, "I trusted Peter yesterday" and "I trusted Peter" are sentences with different meanings. The first implies that the trust was yesterday (started in the past, ended in the past). The latter does not implies that trust has been revoked (simple past tense). Similarly, "I trusted Peter" and "I trusted Peter today" have two different meanings.

Answer (score 2):

Emphasis can definitely change the meaning of either sentence, or likely, any sentence. To me, however, the primary difference—at least written, without formatting to indicate emphasis—between these two sentences is that “until now” expresses a firm and final limit on the time being discussed. Where “before” is somewhat more neutral, suggesting it was true in the past, but not *necessarily* that it is no longer true or won’t be true in the future.

So for your purpose, I’d say “until now” is more fitting.

But, particularly in context, or with emphasis, it’s unlikely that either phrasing would be misunderstood. Even at its most neutral, “I’ve always trusted Peter before,” does *not* sound confident in the speaker’s ability to continue trusting Peter in this instance.¹

1. <sub>Unless, as Old Brixtonian suggests, context or emphasis suggests that the concern in this sentence is more on “Peter,” vs. someone else—this sentence could easily be used in response to someone suggesting the speaker trust someone other than Peter, without necessarily meaning they should stop trusting Peter. Maybe Peter isn’t even relevant to the conversation and the sense here is more “Well, I’ve always trusted Peter before, and that worked out, so now I can trust you, too,” or something. But it would take context to build up that kind of meaning.</sub>